# Packages in Proget not publishing to feed

Tags: teamcity, nuget, proget

My company uses Team City to build and push packages to an internal Proget server. The problem that I am having is that many of the packages are not showing up in my Proget feed. Everything executes fine in Team City and the logs show that that the package(s) were pushed to the server successfully, but they do not show up in the feed.

If I go to the feed path manually, I can see the packages in the folder, it just seems like Proget isn't seeing them or something. Is this an issue with Team City, Proget, or something else?

Also, I have made sure that the 'Only upload package but do not publish it to feed' option in Team City is unchecked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same problem some time ago.
In my case I had to restart proget and force the feed reindexing.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree, a service restart should help, and restart the indexing process.